# Weird output in my mac iTerm bash shell. How do I make it clean?

Tags: bash, shell

Setting up my bash and made some mistake. Here is my bash shell:

```
android-c26f663baae722eb:~ okyretina$
```

I have used a clean .bash_profile and sourced it and the shell still have that weird `android-c26f663baae722eb`

The command that did that I believe is this:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u@\h:\W" "\\\$ ";'
```

which I got from [here](https://gist.github.com/burpnoes/9116314)

Seems to work initially then that android- thing pops up and I can never removed it. I clean my bash profile and tried everything. Nothing seems to work. Also, while trying to understand export vs just setting the variable directly, I did

```
export PS1='\[\e[0;91m\]\u@\h\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;92m\]\w\[\e[m\]\[\e[0;93m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[00m\] \[\e[0;96m\]\$ \[\e[m\]\[\e[0;97m\]'
```

or some variation and now the color is gone. It used to just be

```
PS1='\[\e[0;91m\]\u@\h\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;92m\]\w\[\e[m\]\[\e[0;93m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[00m\] \[\e[0;96m\]\$ \[\e[m\]\[\e[0;97m\]'
```

At this point, I just want a clean shell. Starting terminal.app also results in the same output which makes me think it's not an iTerm issue. How do I fix this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is the hostname assigned by your DNS server. Try resolving your IP address and see if it returns that hostname:

host [your IP]

It might be a dynamic DNS assignment from a previous Android device.Try restarting and/or flushing your DNS server.or configure a fixed hostname in the DNS server.

I have seen this behavior on our corporate network.

Comment: host ipaddress returns Host.#####.in-addr.arpa. not found

Comment: how do i restart and or flush DNS server?

Comment: Are you on a home network? Then just reset your router.if you're on a corporate network you should ask your admin.

Comment: Wow! Super weird! But I did get home. Run a new shell and it's back to normal